# Get X and Y Cordinates from Vector2

Tags: python, vector, pygame, output, coordinates

How can i determine the x and y coordinates of a [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) object?

```py
self.position = Vector2(x, y)
```

This is the Output from x and y in Vector2:

```py
[5,14.5]
```

Comment: Without knowing what `Vector2()` is it is very hard to help.

Comment: its a import: from pygame.math import Vector2

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2):

> The coordinates of a vector can be retrieved or set using attributes
> or subscripts
>
> ```
> v = pygame.Vector3()
>
> v.x = 5 
> v[1] = 2 * v.x 
> print(v[1]) # 10
>
> v.x == v[0] 
> v.y == v[1] 
> v.z == v[2]
> ```
>
> Multiple coordinates can be set using slices or swizzling
>
> ```
> v = pygame.Vector2()  
> v.xy = 1, 2  
> v[:] = 1, 2
> ```

Comment: Just use `self.position.x` and `self.position.y`, as you can see in the example.

Comment: I literally did that in my last comment

Comment: I have no idea what you expect